# jQuery - Can't get the proper id to click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have html like this

```
<div class="ui pagination menu">
<li class="active item">1</li>
<li class="item"><a href="http://localhost/csgorakCI/market/2" data-ci-pagination-page="2">2</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="http://localhost/csgorakCI/market/2" data-ci-pagination-page="2" rel="next"><i class="right chevron icon"></i></a></li>
</div>
```

i want to click the link and get the data attribute data-ci-pagination-page

and this is my jquery code

```
$('li.item').on('click','a',function () { 
    var link = $(this).attr("data-ci-pagination-page");
    console.log(link);
    load_result(link);
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: Its working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/L3w1tyq6/

Comment: What are you trying to do with `data-ci-pagination-page` ? Please post your `load_result` function.

Comment: `function load_result(index) {
   index = index || 0;
   $.post("http://localhost/csgorakCI/market/" + index, {
    ajax: true
   },function(data) {
    console.log(data.results[4].img);
    $("#result_table").html(result_template({itemData: data.results}));
    $('#ajax_pagingsearc').html(data.pagination);
    $(".item_img").unveil();
   }, "json");
  }
  load_result();`

Comment: What's the issue? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Sweeeeep Put it in the question, not a comment.

Comment: no error in console appear when i click the link the jquery not functioning keeps open the link :( sorry rip english

Comment: BTW, you can use `$(this).data('ci-pagination-page')`

Comment: when i try the code in other file its working when i put it in my file it's not working

Comment: BTW im using Handlebars , does Handlebars is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved :)

```
$(document).on('click','a[data-ci-pagination-page]',function () { 
    var link = $(this).data("ci-pagination-page");
    load_result(link);
    return false;
});
```

ty for helping :) :)